# Angular 5 formGroup formControlName issue with select options

Tags: typescript, angular5, form-control, formgroups

**Update**

We are using Angular5 and we have a form that is constructed using FormGroup and then binded using formgroup and formControlName.

On initial load everything is populating correctly in all input fields. After closing the modal and then clicking on another record populates all fields with the correct userFrm value except the Salutation and AwardStatus Dropbox. If you click back on the first record then the values are correct. This has been causing issues for us. I'm pretty sure it is the [Selected[ property is not updating.

**user.component.ts snippet**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.indLoading = true;
        this.loadSalutationField();
        this.loadResearchField();
        this.loadTrustField();
        this.loadRegionField();
        this.loadAwardStatusField();
        this.loadRoleField();
        this.loadUsers();
        this.indLoading = false;
        this.createForm();
    }

    createForm() {
        this.userFrm = new FormGroup({
            UserKey: new FormControl(''),
            SiID: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            OrcidID: new FormControl(''),
            Salutation: new FormControl({}),
            FirstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            Surname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            CurrentPost: new FormControl(''),
            Department: new FormControl(''),
            Institution: new FormControl(''),
            Region: new FormControl({}),
            PrimaryResearchField: new FormControl({}),
            SecondaryResearchField: new FormControl({}),
            NHSTrust: new FormControl({}),
            Street: new FormControl(''),
            City: new FormControl(''),
            County: new FormControl(''),
            Postcode: new FormControl(''),
            Telephone: new FormControl(''),
            Mobile: new FormControl(''),
            Email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            Fax: new FormControl(''),
            SecondaryEmail: new FormControl(''),
            ProfessionalBackground: new FormControl(''),
            ApprovalStatus: new FormControl(''),
            Biography: new FormControl(''),
            NIHRAccount: new FormControl(''),
            IsCurrent: new FormControl(''),
            AwardStatusDate: new FormControl(''),
            CreatedDate: new FormControl(''),
            UpdatedDate: new FormControl(''),
            IsActive: new FormControl(''),
            Image: new FormControl({}),
            AwardStatus: new FormControl({}),
            Role: new FormControl({})
        });
    }

updateUserForm() {
        this.userFrm.setValue({
            UserKey: this.user.UserKey,
            SiID: this.user.SiID,
            OrcidID: this.user.OrcidID,
            Salutation: this.user.Salutation,
            FirstName: this.user.FirstName,
            Surname: this.user.Surname,
            CurrentPost: this.user.CurrentPost,
            Department: this.user.Department,
            Institution: this.user.Institution,
            Region: this.user.Region,
            PrimaryResearchField: this.user.PrimaryResearchField,
            SecondaryResearchField: this.user.SecondaryResearchField,
            NHSTrust: this.user.NHSTrust,
            Street: this.user.Street,
            City: this.user.City,
            County: this.user.County,
            Postcode: this.user.Postcode,
            Telephone: this.user.Telephone,
            Mobile: this.user.Mobile,
            Email: this.user.Email,
            Fax: this.user.Fax,
            SecondaryEmail: this.user.SecondaryEmail,
            ProfessionalBackground: this.user.ProfessionalBackground,
            ApprovalStatus: this.user.ApprovalStatus,
            Biography: this.user.Biography,
            NIHRAccount: this.user.NIHRAccount,
            IsCurrent: this.user.IsCurrent,
            AwardStatusDate: this.user.AwardStatusDate,
            CreatedDate: this.user.CreatedDate,
            UpdatedDate: this.user.UpdatedDate,
            IsActive: this.user.IsActive,
            Image: this.user.Image,
            AwardStatus: this.user.AwardStatus,
            Role: this.user.Role
        });

editUser(userKey: number) {
        this.dbops = DBOperation.update;
        this.setControlsState(true);
        this.createForm();
        this.modalTitle = "Edit User";
        this.modalBtnTitle = "Update";
        this.user = this.users.filter(x => x.UserKey === userKey)[0];
        this.dangerousImage = "data:image/jpg;base64," + this.user.Image.ImageStream;
        this.trustedImage = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.dangerousImage);
        this.updateUserForm();
        this.editModal.open();
    }
```

**user.component.html**

```
<bs-modal #editModal [keyboard]="false" [backdrop]="'static'">
    <form [formGroup]="userFrm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
        <!--<pre>{{userFrm.value | json}}</pre>-->
        <bs-modal-header>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
        </bs-modal-header>
        <bs-modal-body>
            <div class="square">
                <img [src]="trustedImage" />
                <button (click)="updateUserPhoto(user.UserKey)">Upload Image</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="isAdmin">
                <span>Role*</span>
                <select class="form-group" formControlName="Role">
                    <option *ngFor="let role of roles"
                            [value]="role"
                            [selected]="role.Description === userFrm.value.Role.Description">
                        {{role.Description}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="isAdmin">
                <span>
                    Award Status*
                </span>
                <select class="form-group" formControlName="AwardStatus">
                    <option *ngFor="let awardStatus of awardStatues"
                            [value]="awardStatus"
                            [selected]="awardStatus.Description == userFrm.value.AwardStatus.Description">
                        {{awardStatus.Description}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>SI Number*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Si Number" formControlName="SiID" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Title*</span>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="Salutation">
                    <option *ngFor="let salutationfield of salutationfields"
                            [value]="salutationfield"
                            [selected]="salutationfield.Description === userFrm.value.Salutation.Description">
                        {{salutationfield.Description}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>First name*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" formControlName="FirstName" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Surname*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" formControlName="Surname" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Orchid ID*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="OrcidID" formControlName="OrcidID" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Telephone*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone" formControlName="Telephone" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Email*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" formControlName="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Current Post*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Post" formControlName="CurrentPost" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Institution*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Institution" formControlName="Institution" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Department*</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Department" formControlName="Department" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>NHS Trust*</span>
                <select formControlName="NHSTrust">
                    <option *ngFor="let trustfield of trustfields"
                            [value]="trustfield"
                            [selected]="trustfield.Description === userFrm.value.NHSTrust.Description">
                        {{trustfield.Description}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Region*</span><br />
                <select formControlName="Region">
                    <option *ngFor="let regionfield of regionfields"
                            [value]="regionfield"
                            [selected]="regionfield.Description === userFrm.value.Region.Description">
                        {{regionfield.Description}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Primary Research Field*</span><br />
                <select formControlName="PrimaryResearchField">
                    <option *ngFor="let priResearchField of researchfields"
                            [value]="priResearchField"
                            [selected]="priResearchField.Description === userFrm.value.PrimaryResearchField.Description">
                        {{priResearchField.Description}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Secondary Research Field*</span><br />
                <select formControlName="SecondaryResearchField">
                    <option *ngFor="let secResearchField of researchfields"
                            [value]="secResearchField"
                            [selected]="secResearchField.Description === userFrm.value.SecondaryResearchField.Description">
                        {{secResearchField.Description}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <accordion>
                    <accordion-group heading="Biography">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Biography" formControlName="Biography" />
                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>
            </div>
        </bs-modal-body>
        <bs-modal-footer>
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="editModal.close()">Cancel</a>
                <button type="submit" [disabled]="userFrm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">{{modalBtnTitle}}</button>
            </div>
        </bs-modal-footer>
    </form>
</bs-modal>
```

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Lewis

Comment: Did you try to put `this.userFrm = this.fb.group({...})` directly in the constructor? Not using it as a separated function and then invoke it when initializing the component `constructor(){this.createUserForm();}`. Try this: `import {FormGroup, ...} from '@angular/forms'; export class UserComponent { public userFrm: FormGroup; constructor(){this.userFrm = this.fb.group({ UserKey: [''],...})  } }`

Comment: Hi @k.vincent I have tried that and also tried placing it directly within the ngOnInit()

Comment: Do you get any error or something similar? We might need more input to be to localize the issue.

Comment: I have updated the issue above after going through and refactoring the userFrm. The issue where the dropdown values is now resolved and the correct values are populating in all but 2 of the select elements (AwardStatus and Salutation). The first record that i click on works and populates correctly. Using the <pre>{{userFrm.value | json}}</pre> i have been able to keep an eye on the userFrm to make sure its updating the data which it is. However the [Selected] property does not seem to be working correctly.

Comment: One thing I would like to mention... why are you creating an instance of `FormControl` every time for each field? Is there any reason? I would instead use `FormBuilder` from `@angular/forms`... this would save you a lot of code, make the code maintainable and avoid any unexpected bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after angular 4 [compareWith], was introduced. This replaces [selected] when using ngValue and FormGroups

See this question for more information

[Angular 4 - Reactive Forms - select item in a list from object not referenced in this list - trackby issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369344/angular-4-reactive-forms-select-item-in-a-list-from-object-not-referenced-in)