# selected attribute not working when formcontrol is on select tag

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

**Expected behavior**

would like when selected value is set to have that option set in the select drop down

**HTML Code:**

```
<select id="products" class="form-control new-select padding" formControlName="featured_product">
 <option>Please Select</option> 
<option *ngFor="let p of products" [ngValue]="p" [attr.selected]="p.ProductId == product.ProductId ? '': null" >{{p.ProductName}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: **Solution for above question** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369344/angular-4-reactive-forms-select-item-in-a-list-from-object-not-referenced-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369344/angular-4-reactive-forms-select-item-in-a-list-from-object-not-referenced-in)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select id="products" class="form-control new-select padding" formControlName="featured_product">
   <option>Please Select</option> 
   <option *ngFor="let p of products" [value]="p" [attr.selected]="p.ProductId == product.ProductId ? '': null" >{{p.ProductName}}</option>
 </select>
```

I have tried this code and its working fine.

```
products = [{ProductId: 1, ProductName : 'a'},
   {ProductId: 2, ProductName : 'ab'},
   {ProductId: 3, ProductName : 'abc'},
   {ProductId: 4, ProductName : 'abcd'} ];

product =  {ProductId: 2, ProductName : 'ab'};
```